# List with four levels not working

Tags: lists, enumitem

Following list is supposed to typeset four levels but it's combining the third and fourth levels as shown in the image below.

**Note**:

1. I'm using MikTeX's latest version released in November, 2016.
2. For easy reading, I've used numbers 1, 2, 3, 4 respectively at the end of each level item text. E.g., Test3**2** is second level item, Test5**3** is third level item etc.

**LateX file**:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{enumitem}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}
          \item Test11
          \item Test21
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item Test32
                    \item Test42
                    \begin{itemize}
                         \item Test53
                         \item Test63
                    \end{itemize}
                    \begin{itemize}
                          \item Test74
                          \item Test84
                    \end{itemize}
                \end{itemize}
         \item Test91
        \item Test101
    \end{enumerate}

    \end{document}
```

**Typeset Display in TeXworks**:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put the fourth level within the third:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
      \item Test11
      \item Test21
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Test32
                \item Test42
                \begin{itemize}
                     \item Test53
                     \item Test63
                     \begin{itemize}
                        \item Test74
                        \item Test84
                     \end{itemize}
                \end{itemize}
            \end{itemize}
     \item Test91
    \item Test101
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]